# Java Actionlistener on Button

Tags: java, actionlistener

```
import java.awt.*;

public class TestButton {
  private Frame f;
  protected Button b;

  public TestButton() {
    f = new Frame("Test");
    b = new Button("Press Me!");
    b.setActionCommand("ButtonPressed");
  }

  public void launchFrame() {
    b.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    f.add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestButton guiApp = new TestButton();
    guiApp.launchFrame();
  }
}

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonHandler extends TestButton implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object source = e.getSource();
      if(source==b)
      {
            System.out.println("Action occurred");
            System.out.println("Button's command is: "
                               + e.getActionCommand());
      }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to invoke a ActionEvent when the button b is pressed but not working with getSource.

Comment: What do you get in source? null or another parameter?

Answer (score 8):

You're misusing inheritance. The ButtonHandler class should not extend the TestButton class, since the b variable in the handler class refers to a completely different Button object from the one displayed. I suggest:

- Use the Swing library, not the AWT library
- You can get the JButton pressed from the ActionEvent's `getSource()` method and use it directly.
- If you need a reference to the GUI in the handler, pass in a reference in the handler's constructor.
- Don't misuse inheritance to solve problems that don't involve inheritance issues.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestButton extends JPanel {
   private JButton btn = new JButton(new ButtonAction("Press Me!", "ButtonPressed"));

   public TestButton() {
      add(btn);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      TestButton testButton = new TestButton();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestButton");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(testButton  );
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
   public ButtonAction(String name, String actionCommand) {
      super(name);
      putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, actionCommand);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      System.out.println("Button's actionCommand is: " + evt.getActionCommand());
   }
}
```

Comment: That is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you extends `TestButton` in your `ButtonHandler`, because of you have 2 different instances of your `Button` and thea are not equals.

To fix that you can remove `extends TestButton` and make `ButtonHandler` as inner class of `TestButton`

or you can compare action commands instead of `Button`'s like next:

```
  if(((Button)source).getActionCommand().equals("ButtonPressed"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove extends TestButton as the 2 different instances of the buttons are not equal. You should go for a ButtonHandler as inner class or anonymous class to implement this.

Check this question:
[Java Button Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473590/java-button-handler)